# Definition of capacity of cut in a flow network

Tags: algorithm

Hi I was thinking I did understand the topic. But when I solved the problem I was confused.

I think the cut should be like this see pic below. So the result should be 11 + 12 - 4 = 23-4 = 19
because its flowing out from A to B
from v2 to v4 = 11
from v1 to v3 = 12

B to A flowing in
from v3 to v2 = 4

But why is the solution 9? What did I do wrongly? Thanks for you help!
[image]

Comment: Your calculation of the capacity of a cut is fine, you only did a mistake on the placement of your cut. You cut between `{s, v1, v2}` and `{v3,v4,t}`, the exercise asks you to cut between `{s, v2, v4}` and `{t, v1, v3}`.

Comment: hi thanks I tried again and did a new cut. But I still think its wrong right?

Comment: Yes it's still wrong, I'm making an answer to show you the right one.

Comment: The correct answer is flow=19, capacity=31.  All of the things in the question are important, like where they tell you which vertices are on either side of the cut, and where they tell you what the number 9 refers to.

Comment: thanks 
flow = 11+1-4+7+4 = 19 and capacity 16+4 - 9 + 7 +4 = 22? But why 31? Then I don't have to consider the diagonal line with the cost 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method to calculate a cut's capacity is correct, it was you way of cutting that was mistaken.

Here is the right cut (green line):
[image: Yes]

For an explanation of a cut's capacity in a graph, have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987418/definition-of-capacity-of-cut-in-a-flow-network)

Following @Matt Timmermans' comment: as he said, the flow is 19, and capacity is 31 in this example.

Comment: basically, just sum the capacities going from S to V\S (and do not substract the arcs going in the other direction).

Comment: Thanks alot m.raynal. Just one question about the cut. Is it wrong if I cut between sv2and v3t? The other way of the diagonal?

Comment: If you want to cut between `{s, v2, v4}` and `{t, v1, v3}`, then you can't cut the edge `(s, v2)` because `s` and `v2` are in the same subset `{s, v2, v4}`.